# Monitoring /proc/net/udp

Tags: monitoring, udp

I am interested in tracking changes in /proc/net/udp, particularly in the "drops" column.  I want to know the the approximate time when a drop counter goes up.  Also, if the socket gets destroyed, I want a record of what the drop count was.

I am thinking about running a cronjob every 5 seconds to check for changes and then log them.

Is there a better way of monitoring this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's your best option.